# Limit points of a sequence

Tags: calculus, general-topology

The limit points of the sequence $x_n=(1-\frac{1}{n}, \cos n\pi , \frac{1}{n}), n\in N$ is (1,1,0) and (1,-1,0)? If yes, why exactly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It suffices to look at even and odd terms: $x_{2k}=(1-1/(2k),1,1/(2k))\rightarrow(1,1,0)$ and $x_{2k+1}=(1-1/(2k+1),-1,1/(2k+1))\rightarrow(1,-1,0)$.

Comment: Why these points is the unique limit points of this sequence?

Comment: For any limit point, you can find a convergent subsequence to that. If that subsequence has infinitely many even terms, it is a subsequence of that even sequence, likewise, if the subsequence has infinitely many odd terms, it is a subsequence of that odd sequence.

Comment: And that subsequence cannot have infinitely many even and odd terms together, it will lead to a contradiction.

Comment: Oh, I see it why because $\cos (k_n \pi )$ converges to 1 or -1 and $1-\frac{1}{k_n}$ converges to 1 and $\frac{1}{k_n}$  converges to 0

Comment: The good thing about the $\cos$ is that, the value is fixed either $1$ or $-1$.

Comment: Yes it's clear to me now...Thanks